# Issue with setBigDecimal by prepared statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, bigdecimal

I have a prepared statement. I call

```
stmt.setBigDecimal(BigDecimal.valueOf("0.9"))
```

the problem is that in the database 0.90000000000000000000 is saved instead of 0.9.

I use Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0.

Is BigDecimal not understood by the driver or make the driver do something wrong?

Comment: What is the full definition of that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you indicate that the datatype is DECIMAL(36,20), it is totally logical: 36,20 means: 36 numbers precision, of which there are 20 after the decimal separator.

If you save 0.9 in DECIMAL(36,20), it will be 0.90000000000000000000 (which has 20 positions after the decimal separator) as that is the specified precision for the field.

Comment: thx, yes it is logical, right. But I find this not so clever... I mean if than I read the value from the database all the calculations are done using 20 decimal positions...

Comment: If that is not what you want, you should use a smaller scale in the DECIMAL datatype in the database, or cast the field to a smaller scale DECIMAL type in your select.

Answer (score 1):

The precision on the column is likely what is causing this.  It is likely it was declared as numeric with no specific precision or scale.

Comment: It is declared as decimal(36, 20)